# Braking down amp tubes schematics (EL86, ECC83, ECF80)

Tags: amplifier

Hey I got schematics for the tubes in the title. What are the values in the black circles (for ECC83 and ECF80)? 
EL86: What do the shapes with the numbers inside them represent? What do the numbers in them describe?
[image]

Comment: Voltage. And the black rectangles are current (mA)

Answer (score 3):

The squares seem to be bias currents, the circles bias voltages. In the first example, we see the top circle with 6.3 in it and the square with 0.7. They are connected to the heater element. If you go look up the datasheet, you will find that you are supposed to apply a voltage of 6.3 V RMS on the heater, and this should give an RMS current of maximum 0.7 A.

The same can be found for the other tubes, where they will be the bias voltages and currents for a given operating point.

Comment: Not just bias : 6.3/0.3 are heater voltage/current.

Comment: @BrianDrummond as these are DC operating point voltages I consider them bias voltage as well. From what I understand any voltage/current that is needed to establish a specific operating point is a bias voltage/current.

Comment: That's an unusual use of the term "bias" in vacuum tube circuits. And one of the voltages is quite obviously AC...

Comment: @BrianDrummond very valid point. I guess it's just my IC background.